# How to debug a .Net Remoting service

Tags: c#, .net, .net-remoting

I've to add a .Net service to an existing application(which already use .Net remoting for the whole thing).

I've some issues("Failed to write to an IPC Port: The pipe is being closed") just when I do the first call after my connection.

I'm trying to enable more details, like I can do with the WCF tracing.

Is there something equivalent? How to enable it? Where the logs will be placed?

Comment: In the client side of your code if you provide the connectionTimeout value, the problem will be solved.

Comment: @Thennarasan but this happens like 20ms after I did opened the IPC Channel.

Comment: This is the usual message in IPC communication via named pipes when the other side of the channel closes the pipe. It's hard to tell you more about it; you simply need to check up your logic. Log all key points in the communication from both parts in a single event log using System.EventLog. To find out the source of the problem, you need to understand the order of operation as it is supposed to be.

Comment: Well, my question is about how to log this kind of information. I can enable a Trace for WCF; but how to do it in .Net Remoting

Comment: This is what I referred when developing a small application in my end, Give a try `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.services.trackingservices(v=vs.85).aspx`

Comment: @Thennarasan I'm unable to access your link. Also something: I'm currently "adding" one property to our service(which gives access to another part of our server), they are on the same channel, and I can still access the other channel just fine, it just seems to be an issue with one particular part of the service, so I don't think it's channel related, but I need to get more information to understand what is happening